# Automatic fill in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a docx template of a contract in which in each page the tenant's name and date has to be typed.
Instead of writing the name and the date all over again in each page, is there an option of displaying an input box in the beginning when the file is being opened so that the name and the date are typed only once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming tenant name and date isn't repeating in header but on different pages in the body of text?

You could use a FILL-IN field to prompt for name of tenant.  Then create a bookmark around that FILL-IN field.  You can then insert a cross-reference to the bookmark text elsewhere in your document.

To update the tenant name, select the entire document with CTRL a and press F9 key to update fields.  This will display the prompt for tenant name.  Once you type in the name and press enter, the FILL-IN field and the cross-references to that bookmark text will update.

Similarly you can use an ASK field, and you can name the bookmark at this point in the Insert Field dialog.  To update, again select document and press F9 and the ASK prompts will be triggered.